# C++: Read strings and integers from file, and obtain highest number

Tags: c++

I wrote the code below in attempt to read string and integer from a text file, where the integer is the highest number (score) with its corresponding string (player). I'm able to `cout` the content of the file but how do I test which number is the highest and how do I link it to its player? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

**The content of text file:**

```
Ronaldo 
10400 
Didier 
9800 
Pele 
12300 
Kaka 
8400 
Cristiano 
8000
```

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

int main() { 


    string text;
    string player;

    int scores;
    ifstream scoresFile;


    // Open file
    scoresFile.open("scores.txt");

    // Check if file exists
    if (!scoresFile) {
        cerr << "Unable to open file: scores.txt" << endl;
        exit(0); // Call system to stop
    }
    else {
        cout << "File opened successfully, program will continue..." << endl << endl << endl;

        // Loop through the content of the file
        while (scoresFile >> text) {

        cout << text << endl;

        }
    }

    // Close file
    scoresFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RochMoure make sure the example data is formatted as it is in your file. Your original post had blank lines between each line of data. Presumably that isn't how the data is in the file. It would make more sense if each line contained `"Name Number"` rather than having each on a separate line -- but that is the way you have it.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the way it is set up, but after reading all posts, I was able to accomplish the result, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable `string bestplayer`, `string currentplayer` and `int bestscore = 0`.  I would increment an integer each time you read a line.  Then, you take the the modulus of it with respect to two (`i % 2`), and if it is odd, you output the stream to `currentplayer`.  If it is even, output the stream to a temporary integer and compare it with `bestscore`.  If it is higher than `bestscore`, set the value of `bestscore` to that integer and set `bestplayer = currentplayer`.  Best of luck!

Comment: Why not just read a name and then a number? Seems awfully complicated to have variables denoting which field is being read

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen how would you implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `exit()` when you don't absolutely have to. `exit()` won't do any stack unwinding and circumvent the principle of RAII. In `main()` you can easily use `return EXIT_FAILURE;` to end the program in case of an error.

Talking about RAII: Use the constructor to give a `class` its values, eg. use `std::ifstream scoresFile{ "scores.txt" }; instead of`scoresFile.open("scores.txt");`. Also, there is no need to call`scoresFile.close()` since the destructor will take care of that.

Don't use `std::endl` if all you want to say is `'\n'` (or `"...\n"`). `std::endl` will not only insert a newline character (`'\n'`) into the stream, but also flush it. If you really want to flush the stream then be explicit and write `std::flush` instead of `std::endl`.

Now to the problem at hand. The elegant solution would be to have an object that represents a `player` which consists of the players name and its score. Such an object may not only be used to read the highscore list but also during gameplay.

For the sake of input and output one would overload stream insertion and extraction operators.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 

class player
{
    std::string name;
    int score;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, player const &p);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, player &p);

public:
    bool operator>(player const &other) { return score > other.score; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, player const &p)
{
    os << p.name << '\n' << p.score;
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, player &p)
{
    player temp_player;
    if (is >> temp_player.name >> temp_player.score)
        p = temp_player; // only write to p if extraction was successful.
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    char const * scoresFileName{ "scores.txt" };
    std::ifstream scoresFile{ scoresFileName };

    if (!scoresFile) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file \"" << scoresFileName << "\"!\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "File opened successfully, program will continue...\n\n";

    player p;
    player highscore_player;

    while (scoresFile >> p) { // extract players until the stream fails
        if (p > highscore_player) // compare the last extracted player against the previous highscore
            highscore_player = p; // and update the highscore if needed
    }

    std::cout << "Highscore:\n" << highscore_player << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, you guys rock!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to overloading the `<<` operator, you can take more of a procedural approach and simply check whether the first character in the line read is a digit, and if so convert to an `int` with `std::stoi` and compare against your current max score, updating if it is greater.

Your data file layout is a bit odd, but presuming it is what you have to work with, you can simply read the first line as the first name, and store the name as say `lastname` at the end of the read loop so that it is available when you read your integer on the next line.

Making use of `std::exception` to validate the `std::stoi` conversion will insure you are dealing with valid integer data before making your comparison and updating the high score, e.g.

```
    // Loop through the content of the file
    while (scoresFile >> text) {
        if ('0' <= text[0] && text[0] <= '9') { /* is 1st char digit? */
            try {   /* try and convert to int */
                int tmp = stoi (text);
                if (tmp > scores) {         /* if tmp is new high score */
                    scores = tmp;           /* assign to scores */
                    player = lastplayer;    /* assign lastplayer to player */
                }
            }   /* handle exception thrown by conversion */
            catch ( exception& e) {
                cerr << "error: std::stoi - invalid argument or error.\n" <<
                        e.what() << '\n';
            }
        }
        else    /* if 1st char not a digit, assign name to lastplayer */
            lastplayer = text;

    }
```

Another note. When initializing a variable to use in a *greater-than* comparison, you should initialize the value to `INT_MIN` to insure you handle negative values correctly. (and for *lesser-than* comparisons, initialize to `INT_MAX`)

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() { 


    string text;
    string player;
    string lastplayer;

    int scores = numeric_limits<int>::min();    /* intilize to INT_MIN */
    ifstream scoresFile;

    // Open file
    scoresFile.open("scores.txt");

    // Check if file exists
    if (!scoresFile) {
        cerr << "Unable to open file: scores.txt" << endl;
        exit(0); // Call system to stop
    }

    cout << "File opened successfully, program will continue..." << 
            endl << endl;

    // Loop through the content of the file
    while (scoresFile >> text) {
        if ('0' <= text[0] && text[0] <= '9') { /* is 1st char digit? */
            try {   /* try and convert to int */
                int tmp = stoi (text);
                if (tmp > scores) {         /* if tmp is new high score */
                    scores = tmp;           /* assign to scores */
                    player = lastplayer;    /* assign lastplayer to player */
                }
            }   /* handle exception thrown by conversion */
            catch ( exception& e) {
                cerr << "error: std::stoi - invalid argument or error.\n" <<
                        e.what() << '\n';
            }
        }
        else    /* if 1st char not a digit, assign name to lastplayer */
            lastplayer = text;

    }
    // Close file
    scoresFile.close();

    cout << "Highest Player/Score: " << player << "/" << scores << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rdnamenum2
File opened successfully, program will continue...

Highest Player/Score: Pele/12300
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.